# pyqt print preview QTableView

Tags: python, printing, pyqt, qtableview, qpainter

I'm trying to print the contents of a QTableView to the printer . i implement bottom script and it run successfully without any error. but all data are Unusual in printPreview. this is [pic](http://img4up.com/up2/75917679167425743216.png) from my problem -[FOUNTAIN](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/3796-QTableView-printing?highlight=Qprinter)

```
def printTable(self,printer,painter,area):
    model = self.model
    myTableView = self.view
    printer = painter 
    rows = model.rowCount();
    columns = model.columnCount();
    totalWidth = 0.0;
    totalPageHeight = 0.0;
    totalHeight = 0.0;
    for c in range(columns):
        totalWidth += myTableView.columnWidth(c)

    for p in range(45):
        totalPageHeight += myTableView.rowHeight(p);

    for r in range(rows):
        totalHeight += myTableView.rowHeight(r);

    xscale = area.width() / totalWidth;
    yscale = area.height() / totalHeight;
    pscale = area.height() / totalPageHeight;
    painter.scale(xscale, pscale);
    painter.translate(area.x() + xscale, area.y() + yscale);

    x=0
    #QStyleOptionViewItem option;

    for r in range(rows):
        ++x
        for c in range(columns):
            idx = model.index(r,c);
            option = myTableView.viewOptions();
            option.rect = myTableView.visualRect(idx);
            if r % 2 == 0:
                brush= QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(220, 220, 220), QtCore.Qt.SolidPattern);
                painter.fillRect(option.rect, brush);
            myTableView.itemDelegate().paint(painter, option, idx);

        if (x == 45):
            ok = printer.newPage();
            x=0;
            painter.translate(0, -1350);

####################### Now print Table ######################

printer = QtGui.QPrinter()
painter = QtGui.QPainter()
painter.begin(printer )
self.printTable(printer,painter, printer.pageRect())
```

if you have any example that can help me please tell me . thank you so much

Comment: `++x` doesn't do what you think in python. basically it does nothing. other then that it's hard to say without a minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C++, I'll suggest to use a professional reporting tool. Available options are [KDAB reporting tool](http://www.kdab.com/kdab-products/kd-reports/) and [Nocisoft NC Report](http://www.nocisoft.com/ncreport.html). AFAIK there is no reliable reporting library for PyQt...

Comment: I concur with the general point, trying to screen-scrape and image of the widget isn't a very good way to go about this.I've used the QTextDocument class for this sort of thing before. generating tables is a chore, but you can export the output as HTML or PDF very easily as well as printing it.